# Generating Swagger from SAP Gateway?

Tags: api, swagger, sap-gateway

I've setup swagger docs for SAP Gateway services using https://inspector.swagger.io/builder and https://app.swaggerhub.com/

However, the free plan is very limited (3 Public API's), plus the URL is set at app.swaggerhub.com.

Is there any way the Swagger doc be generated in SAP using the same URL as the Gateway service?